# Can a user import only the selected tables into HCL OneTest Data while importing any schema from a database?

Tags: database, import, schema, database-table

When a user imports the schema or sample data set from a database into HCL OneTest Data, then can the user import only the selected tables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. HCL OneTest Data allows user to import the selected tables while importing the schema or sample dataset from the database.